# How do I add a version name to the front of a dynamic image asset in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I have a rails 4 app. I am uploading assets using Carrierwave and it allows me to save resized versions as well as the original.  If I upload 'myimage.jpg'  it will also save 'xs_myimage.jpg' to AWS S3.  The problem is,  the xs version name isn't stored anywhere, so I don't know how to serve that image.

This is my image call in the view:

```
<%=      image_tag (@portfolio.img) %>
```

Some how I'd like to call the xs_myimage.jp:

```
<%=      image_tag 'xs_'(@portfolio.img)%> #I know this doesn't work, its just what I've tried
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Carrierwave` will automatically generate an URL helper for every version of the asset you declare. Consider this:

```
class MyUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  version :xs do
    # ...
  end
end
```

You can then use the generated helper:

```
uploader = MyUploader.new # or get the instance out of your model (@portfolio.img)
uploader.xs.url
```

Comment: Great! I had my Uploader set like that I just didn't know how to do @portfolio.img.xs.url

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this

```
<% 
  parts = @portfilio.img.split('/')
  parts[-1]="xs_#{parts.last}"
  img = parts.join('/')
%>

<%= image_tag img %>
```

But its very bad solution.
If "xs" is a smaller(bigger) size of image why you doesn't use carrierwave thumbs?

Comment: that puts the xs in front of the whole path, like: "xs_https:/region.amazonaws.com/bucketname/my_image.jpg"

Comment: I am uploading many different sizes, that's why I'm not using capybara. Thank you, though.

Comment: oh, I am sorry, I mistake capybara with carrierwave :)

Answer (score 0):

In Carrierwave uploader

```
version :xs do
  process resize_to_limit: [50, 50]
end
```

then in view

```
<%= image_tag(@portfolio.img.xs.url) %>
```